# Installing pyquery mac

Tags: python, macos, pypy, pyquery

I tried installing it with pypm first, and basically have the same experience as I did with pip (for which I have copy/pasted the output below). The installation prompt says that it is installed and for both pip and pypm, pyquery turns up in the installation list. But when I go into the python interpreter, apparently pyquery isn't installed :o

What am I doing wrong?

```
arnab:pybikes arnab$ pip list
cssselect (0.8)
lxml (3.2.3)
pip (1.4.1)
PyBikes (0.2dev)
pypm (1.4.0)
pythonselect (1.3)
requests (2.0.0)
setuptools (1.1.4)
virtualenv (1.10.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

---

```
arnab:pybikes arnab$ pip install pyquery
Downloading/unpacking pyquery
  Downloading pyquery-1.2.8.zip (42kB): 42kB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pyquery

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml>=2.1 in /Users/arnab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyquery)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect in /Users/arnab/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from pyquery)
Installing collected packages: pyquery
  Running setup.py install for pyquery

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
Successfully installed pyquery
Cleaning up...
```

---

```
arnab:pybikes arnab$ pip list
cssselect (0.8)
lxml (3.2.3)
pip (1.4.1)
PyBikes (0.2dev)
pypm (1.4.0)
pyquery (1.2.8)
pythonselect (1.3)
requests (2.0.0)
setuptools (1.1.4)
virtualenv (1.10.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

---

```
arnab:pybikes arnab$ python
Python 2.7.3 (480845e6b1dd, Jul 31 2013, 10:58:28)
[PyPy 2.1.0 with GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang Compiler] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``the future has just begun''
>>>> import pyquery
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyquery
>>>>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Which OS X version are you running on? Are the Python and PyPy versions official release versions or just some daily builds? How did you install your Python?

Answer (score 1):

For mac, I use the easy_install from the terminal command line.You will need to install setuptools first from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools  right at the bottom of the page you can find the mac download. Then unzip the file, and run ez_setup to install it.

I tested this and pyquery installed straight away.
The code I used was:
`sudo easy_install pyquery`
And then I entered my password, and then rebooted python, and typed `import pyquery` on the python console, and that was accepted.

Comment: I don't think `pip` nor `easy_install` is the issue here but I have no experience of any kind of PyPy. On regular Python on Mac, `pip install pyquery` works fine on my Yosemite.